# Best Way to Stage WAR file for Deployment

Tags: glassfish

I'd be curious to know how developers place files on a Linux server for deployment on a GF development server?  Do you just transfer them to a public directory, and then deploy ?

I was thinking of just creating a publicly write-able directory on Linux, and copy files there, wi

This is a dev environment, so we don't need anything fancy like versioning at this point, but I do want to have some semblance of order to the process.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you actually deploy (from IDE, asadmin, admin console).

We made the Glassfish autodeploy directory accessible for all developers in the project. However, automatic deployment is not always suitable, especially during development. A public directory as proposed by you would also be possible.